# In Corda, how to obtain the StateRef of the output states of the current transaction in a flow?

Tags: corda

I am running a flow where I create a transaction with outputs and commit it to the ledger.

I now want to grab the input `StateRef`s corresponding to the outputs of the transaction I just created and commited to ledger.

How can I retrieve these `StateRef`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily construct the `StateRef`s manually.

For example, suppose you have a reference to the signed transaction you just created:

```
stx: SignedTransaction
```

And you want the input `StateRef` of the third output of that transaction. You'd create this as follows:

```
val stateRef: StateRef = StateRef(stx.id, 2)
```